# "Guadagnarsi da vivere": may it also be "guadagnare da vivere"?

Tags: verbs

I have read the following sentence in an Italian learning tool:

> Si guadagna da vivere suonando il violino.
>   (= He/she earns a living playing violin)

Is "guadagnarsi da vivere" the only correct/usual form of that expression or could I say "guadagnare da vivere" too?

Comment: In my opinion the correct form is _Si guadagna da vivere_ ; where "Si" means "for himself/herself"; I think you can just use "Guadagna da vivere" only in spoken language.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ricercando "guadagna da vivere" -"si guadagna da vivere" su Google Libri si trovano parecchi esempi di "guadagna da vivere" senza "si".

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22guadagna+da+vivere%22+-%22si+guadagna+da+vivere%22&client=firefox-b-m&sxsrf=ACYBGNSSOypc6xqrhPZmdDPUIrEmy5zQng:1569171892482&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2uvjp9OTkAhUQAmMBHYGQASYQ_AUICygG

Comment: Ci sono anche false occorrenze, però.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/guadagnare/) suggerisce entrambe le versioni:

> *guadagnare o guadagnarsi la vita (o da vivere), il pane*, ossia il denaro necessario ai bisogni della vita;

Comment: I also want to know if both expressions are usual. Could you please add that to your answer?

Comment: @Alan Evangelista - in my personal experience the reflexive form is more common, but I cannot support that with data. It is just my personal opinion.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista:  A way to see that the form with "guadagnarsi" seems to be more common is searching "guadagna da vivere" in Google Books: practically all the occurences you find are of "si guadagna da vivere". To find  "guadagna da vivere" without "si" you have to search "guadagna da vivere" -"si guadagna da vivere" (see the link on a previous comment) and even then you will find some false occurrences corresponding to "si guadagna da vivere".